# React doesn't render Alert (bootstrap)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, alert, react-bootstrap

I added an Alert to my React, but in the browser I see only plain text. What is the problem?

My component:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Alert variant='warning'>
          This is a warning alert—check it out!
        </Alert>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Bootstrap is already installed

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Have you included the [required stylesheet](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets)?

Comment: Likely your stylesheet.

Comment: @BrianThompson No I missed it. Now it's work. Thank you! :D

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to import stylesheet

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

It was the reason